# When adding "<add-linker name="xsiframe"/> to GWT 2.6 project, I get errors

Tags: java, maven, debugging, intellij-idea, gwt

I am part of a team that manages a GWT application. We use GWT 2.6.

I have been able to successfully debug this project in my browser in the past. A couple of days ago, debugging stopped working altogether and the web app no longer loads in my browser. When trying to open it in a browser, I get the following message:

[Javascript error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDKhv.jpg)

If I remove the following line from my .gwt.xml file, the web app works as expected but I lose the ability to debug in my IDE and in my browser:

```
<add-linker name="xsiframe" />
```

Here's what I've done so far:

- Invalidate Cache / Restart (IDE)
- mvn -U clean install
- git clean (removed all unversioned files and directories)
- Cleared my browser cache, cookies, history, etc...
- Restarted IDE, browser, computer
- Tried in different browsers on different machines

Even after all of that, I still get the same error message.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

*UPDATE:

What's interesting is if I remove that line from my .gwt.xml file, perform a `mvn -U clean install`, clear my browser cache, and run my application - everything works. If I then add the line back to my gwt.xml file, do a `mvn -U clean install`, and DON'T clear my browser cache, then the debugging works as well.

Is this because my browser is using a cached version of my GWT generated Javascript?

I almost never clear my browser cache on a regular basis, it's possible that debugging has only ever worked in the past because it was using a cached version of the GWT Javascript files. The problem occurred when I cleared my browser cache in an attempt to solve a different issue that I was having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message is part of the `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Dictionary` class. Either there is now a timing error (gwt app loads too early and the dictionary isn't ready yet), or something else has also changed, and not just the linker.

To be more specific, your question would need more detail.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Colin! I added an update to my question with more details.

Comment: This very likely isn't related to the linker, except how you load the dictionary that I mentioned. That is where you need to provide more detail - perhaps break out a simple example of your app where all it does is load the dictionary.